# Discord.py Mentioning a Role after command executed

Tags: python, discord

Hi i would like a persons role to be mentioned after being added/removed in a queue.

Example:

!addme

Joe Bloggs from Role{clan} Was added to the queue

```
    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def addme(self, ctx):
        ''': Add yourself to the queue!'''
        author = ctx.message.author
        if self.qtoggle:
            if author.id not in self.queue:
                self.queue.append(author.id)
                await ctx.send('you have been added to the Tablet Crafting Queue.')
            else:
                await ctx.send('you are already in the Tablet Crafting Queue!')
        else:
                await ctx.send('The Tablet Crafting Queue is closed.')

    @commands.command(pass_context=True)
    async def removeme(self, ctx):
        ''': Remove yourself from the queue'''
        author = ctx.message.author
        if author.id in self.queue:
            self.queue.remove(author.id)
            await ctx.send('you have been removed from the Tablet Crafting Queue.')
        else:
            await ctx.send('you were not in the Tablet Crafting Queue.')

    @commands.command(name='queue', pass_context=True)
    async def _queue(self, ctx):
        ''': See who's up next!'''
        server = ctx.message.guild
        message = ''
        for place, member_id in enumerate(self.queue):
            member = discord.utils.get(server.members, id=member_id)
            message += f'**#{place+1}** : {member.mention} : {role.mention}\n'
        if message != '':
            await ctx.send(message)
        else:
            await ctx.send('Tablet Crafting Queue is empty')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that a 'member' can have multiple 'roles' and that a 'member' represents an account and can belong to multiple 'guilds'. As such there doesn't seem to be a way to get a member's role in a guild easily (for a good reason).

It is inefficient, but you may simply have to search through all the roles of a guild looking for the member's highest role.

```
# pseudocode
for role in guild.roles:
    if member in role.members:
        role_title = role.name
```

[Guild Docs - Look into role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#guild)
[Role Docs - Look into members](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#role)

Comment: Thanks very much matey :)